# How do i remove the root element from a JSON returned from API in c#?

Tags: c#, json, api

i have a problem with my Json return:
so what i want to do is getting only one specific part of my JSON, which is returned by an API:

```
                    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(pathProducts + i + ".json"))
                    {
                        await response.Content.CopyToAsync(file);
                    }
```

As you can see here what i am doing now is storing into a path the API return.

Now is basically storing using this format in my generated file:

```
{
 found: 12341
 page:2
 pages:1231
 products: [...]
}
```

what i need to do is to get only the products (and the elements inside it) and store that result in my file instead of the whole JSON return.

Comment: Well, you'd have to parse the JSON instead of writing it straight to disk. You could then use the parsed result however you want. There are *lots* of examples of parsing JSON returned by an HttpClient call online - have you tried any of those yet?

Comment: so is your problem on **reading** a specific element from your JSON or on how to **write** that element back to a file?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to parse json and after this save to file only products

```
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

var json=await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var jsonParsed=JObject.Parse();

using ( var sw = new StreamWriter(pathProducts + i + ".json", false);  )
{
    sw.WriteLine(jsonParsed["products"].ToString());
};
```